# can't find synced share point document in sitefinity in content type -> module name in order to edit

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

I created new connection with SharePoint in order to **sync document from share point to Sitefinity**.

I did manual mapping : https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/select-the-content-to-be-synchronized#manually

After syncing document successfully I can see the document in document library but not in content type were I can edit the synced document.

**-----: UPDATE :-----**

**Content type is** : content type is **dropdown** menu top on dashboard, under which my **dynamic module name is shown**. On clicking on that usually I can see the document list (in my old project, not now) on clicking on any document, I can edit the synced document which is not happening right now.

From document library I can't edit properties of the document which is normal (as I see in my old project)

**-----: END : -----**

I tried to sync document from administration -> SharePoint Site -> sync

**Expected document list in content(drop down menu) -> module name.**

Comment: what do you mean by "not in content type where I can edit the synced document" ? 
Can't you edit it in the document library?

Comment: Thank you for reply @VeselinVasilev. I updated my question

Comment: What content types do you sync from Sharepoint?

Comment: I created a dynamic module using module builder i.e. Certificate which I use as content type. It having different properties, title, location, Document, city, country etc

Comment: So you did a manual mapping as shown here: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/select-the-content-to-be-synchronized#manually ?

Comment: Yes. I did manual mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after making call with the sitefinity team.

Go to manage site -> Configure module (your sites action drop down) -> change the module.

all the document were going inside the default. So I change it to my module name and it works !!!

Many thanks to sitefinity !!!